# clearing javascript object to fix jquery animation

Tags: jquery

I'm working on creating an interactive mobile info page about running injuries and prevention. Here's how it's designed to work:

8 icons are aligned on the page. When the user clicks an icon, all other icons with fade away, while the one that was clicked will animate to the top of the screen.

From here, some informative text will appear that associates with that icon (the text is not shown in the jsfiddle. It's not related to my issue).

A back button will also appear along with the text. If the user clicks the back button, the text will disappear and the icon will animate back to its original position.

The moving icon itself is created using jQuery `clone`. Animations and styles are applied to the clone, and it's hidden when it goes back to the original spot.

When running the jQuery that makes this animation, I store a value `pos` that keeps the original position of the icon that was clicked. This is so that when the user clicks "back", it will return to the correct spot. `pos` is an object that stores the `left` and `top` values, and therefore accessed via `pos.top` and `pos.left`. Here's a snippet of this in action. This stores my original position:

```
$gridImg.click(function() {

    ...

    $clone = $(this).clone();

    var pos = $(this).position();

    $clone.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: pos.left,
        top: pos.top
});
```

Here's a snippet of the HTML for each icon (the images have been replace with creepy smileys:

```
<div class="rice-injury-grid">

    <!-- first icon -->     
    <div data-title="rest" class="grid-img">
        <img id="rest-img"  alt="Rest" src="http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/64/sketchcons-x/smiley-3.png"/>
    </div>

    <!-- second -->
    <div data-title="blister" class="grid-img">
        <img id="blister-img" alt="Blisters" src="http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/64/sketchcons-x/smiley-3.png"/>
    </div>

    <!-- third -->    
    <div data-title="ice" class="grid-img">
        <img id="ice-img" alt="Ice" src="http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/64/sketchcons-x/smiley-3.png"/>
    </div>

    <!-- and so on... -->
```

**My issue is this:** throughout using this app, each time the user chooses an icon, it stores the `pos` value indefinitely, so now every time I hit the 'back' button, the icon returns to each position that's been previously chosen.

I'm looking for a way to clear the `pos` value each time the icon goes back to its original position.

See the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YjWkn/) for a demo. Go through at least 2 separate icon sequences to see the full effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move the scope of `pos` to outside the callback, it all works fine.

Edit: update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YjWkn/3/

```
var pos;
$gridImg.click(function () {
    var imgId = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
    var title = $(this).data('title');
    var copy = "#" + title + "-copy";

    $gridImg.fadeOut(200);

    $clone = $(this).clone();

    pos = $(this).position();
```

I just added `var pos;` right before the binding, and removed the `var` from the statement that sets `pos`.

Edit:

The second issue you are having is because you bind the back button click each and every time you click on an icon.  So the first time you click back it fires once, the second time it fires twice, the third time it fires 3 times and so on and so on.

So I moved the binding to outside the click event.  In doing so, I had to expand the scope of `copy' as well.

```
var pos;
    var copy;
    $backBtn.click(function () {
            $(copy).fadeOut(200);
            $backBtn.fadeOut(200);
            $clone.animate({
                width: '50%',
                top: pos.top,
                left: pos.left
            }, 300);

            setTimeout(function () {
                $clone.fadeOut(200);
                $gridImg.fadeIn(200);
            }, 300);

        });
    $gridImg.click(function () {
```

Comment: This does take it back to the original spot, but it actually looks like the image begins to hang after doing the process several times. Give it a try and you'll see this image sputter a bit on returning

Comment: I updated my fiddle and answer, that was actually a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you make pos a global JS variable, then clear it at the end of the back button function, then it works perfectly.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YjWkn/4/

Global:

```
var pos;
$gridImg = $('.grid-img');
```

Set:

```
pos = $(this).position();
```

Clear:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $clone.fadeOut(200);
    $gridImg.fadeIn(200);
}, 300);
pos = '';
```

Comment: This works as well, but it has the same issue I commented on in Javalsu's answer